# google-services.json in release. How to guarantee that google-services.json is not package in the APK release?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

Once we add google-services.json for integration between flutter app and firebase, it contains our fingerprint (SHA-1 key) generated.
So, if I want to create a app release version, what should I do to remove the fingerprint so it will not me shared in the Play Store?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Once you publish an APK to the play store, that APK's SHA-1 is visible to the entire world.  You can't hide this value.  This is what's used to validate that your APK is authentic.